# Trigger a watch function whenever any variable is changed in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Is there a way I can trigger a Vue.js function whenever a variable within the app changed?

```js
var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#demo',
  data: {
    variable1: 'Foo',
    variable2: 'Bar',
    .....
    .....
    variablen: 'Foo Bar'
  },
  watch: {
    <<any variable>>: function(){
      console.log('any of these variables changed');
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: I don't think this is possible and even if it was I wouldn't recommend it. What's wrong with watching properties individually? Is there something specific you need to do? Maybe there is a simpler solution.

Comment: Let's say I need to trigger a single function, say to update data from a GET request, whenever any variable is updated. In my case, I have about 50 fields to watch for.

Comment: Well probably your data model structure is not the best - you can store all variables in object and then watch whole object and then trigger method.

Comment: @BelminBedak suggested the only solution, but even if you take his advice 50+ properties sounds too much... I think you need to restructure your app. If you need this much data to be stored in your data object you might even look into Vuex.

Comment: Great thoughts guys..Cool! Looks like I'll have to think of a good way to restructure the app.

Comment: @peaceman It's hard to suggest anything because we don't know app structure here and really don't know what OP wants to make :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all, I agree with all comments saying that 50 fields sound like a code smell and that code probably need to be refactored.

Beside that, vue allows you to watch for whole `data object` using `$data` watch and explicitly set it as `deep`

```
  watch: {
    '$data': {
      handler: function(newValue) {
        console.log('Current vaules:' + newValue.FirstName + ' ' + newValue.LastName);
      },
      deep: true
    }
  }
```

Please see this working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/AldoRomo88/0csjt7n0/1/) and this [watch documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-watch) extract

> Option: deep
>
> To also detect nested value changes inside Objects, you need to pass
> in deep: true in the options argument. Note that you don’t need to do
> so to listen for Array mutations.

**Warning**

As @BelminBedak remarks, this example only demonstrates that it is possible to archive but not recommended for production environments.

Comment: Watching whole $data object is least option that he should do.For example is okay, but in real app I won't suggest to do that.

Comment: Totally agree with you @BelminBedak, I've just update answer to add that warning, thanks for pointed it